# How to perform spatial joins in ravendb

Tags: join, ravendb, spatial

I have a large collection of documents containing geospatial point data (among other data). I have another large collection of documents containing polygons (among other data).

I want to filter queries on the point data by whether the points are included in any of the polygons that have a certain property.

Can I do this with RavenDB and if so, how?

**Things I thought about:**

I can't see how I could do this with an index because indexes only map (and/or reduce), so I can not query one collection by another.

I can't just make the query and rely on Raven's result caching, because querying by the set of polygons would quickly make the query length exceed any sensible query length limit.

Answer (score 0):

In RavenDB you can define indexes to deal with spatial data.
Let's assume you have a document with spatial polygon defined as WKT:
(WKT --> Well Known Text markup https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text)

```
public class EventWithWKT
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string WKT { get; set; }
}
```

By polygon WKT I mean something like

```
POLYGON ((30 10, 40 40, 20 40, 10 20, 30 10))
```

Then you can define index that would handle the WKT like this:

```
public class EventsWithWKT_ByNameAndWKT : AbstractIndexCreationTask<EventWithWKT>
{
    public EventsWithWKT_ByNameAndWKT()
    {
        Map = events => from e in events
                        select new
                        {
                            Name = e.Name,
                            WKT = e.WKT
                        };

        Spatial(x => x.WKT, options => options.Geography.Default());
    }
}
```

By calling the "Spatial" method in index definition, RavenDB creates special column that can be then queried with spatial queries.

Now filtering on whether a certain point is within the polygons of the documents or not, can be done with the following query:

```
var results = session
    .Query<EventWithWKT, EventsWithWKT_ByNameAndWKT>()
    .Customize(x => x.RelatesToShape("WKT", "POINT (30 10)", SpatialRelation.Within))
    .ToList();
```

That is not the only way to define and use spatial data. You can read more about RavenDB spatial indexes in those documentation articles:

- [defining spatial indexes](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/csharp/indexes/indexing-spatial-data)
- [querying spatial indexes](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/csharp/client-api/session/querying/how-to-query-a-spatial-index)

Comment: I am, to some extent, aware of spatial indexes. My question is not how to query for point data in a single simple polygon. The question is rather: When both the number of points, _and_ the number of polygons is large (or alternatively a single very complex polygon), how can i find the points within the polygons, without running into any of Raven's safe-by-default limits.

Comment: if you are talking about bypassing query-per-session limit, doing lazy queries is one of the ways to bypassing it (https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/csharp/client-api/session/querying/how-to-perform-queries-lazily). Lazy queries are grouped into one request and processed in parallel on the server

Comment: Also, MULTIPOINT and MULTIPOLYGON can work as well. How many multiple points and polygons can you have for each 'join'? Also, this kind of question is better suited to RavenDB mailing list I think because it might require a discussion (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ravendb)

Comment: I don't really want to bypass sensible limits. I'd like a generally applicable solution (if it exists). As to the amount of points, I'll elaborate to the problem domain at hand: The points are sewer manholes in a city. The polygons are road surfaces. There might be 100K points and 5K polygons of which most are relatively simple, so maybe 20K that define polygons. I would have queries like: "Manholes on roads that are public, and in this bounding box" for example.

Comment: But I'll post it to the mailing list in stead.